# How to make a vivid orange pantone color for a book title, if I need it to be printed in process colors along with some photo?

Tags: adobe-indesign, color, print-production, pantone

I need to print a title for a book cover and it needs to be bright/vivid orange, but it needs to be printed in Process colour along with a photograph.. (to print it at the same time) and i dont know how to do that in Indesign.

Comment: Knowing the Pantone number may help, but note that Pantone spot colours cannot always be achieved in CMYK.

Comment: The ideal way to do this, if money is no object, is of course to have the book cover printed on a five-colour machine which has both CMYK _and_ the orange Pantone ink. Many offset printers offer this, but it will be more expensive than regular four-colour printing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the basic procedure. Be aware not *all* Pantone colors can be achieved via CMYK. And this method relies on auto-conversion within the software. If you have a (printed) Pantone Bridge Formula Guide, you can get the recommended CMYK values from the Formula Guide. That *may* yield a closer match.

If by "vivid orange" you are referring to something such as a fluorescent orange Pantone, you **won't** be able to achieve that via CMYK colors.

---

Add the Pantone color.

Double-click the Pantone color in the **Swatch Panel**

In the **Swatch Options** dialog window, change the drop down for **Color Mode** to `CYMK` and the drop down for **Color Type** to `Process`.

[image]

[image]

Once you do this, you'll notice the icons in the Swatch Panel change to indicate a process color. I, personally, also like to (manually) change the name, adding "proxy". So the name indicates it's *not actually* a spot color.

[image]

The color will then separate in 4 process colors.